# Echo Mysqli query with POST variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

want i want is to query my db with post variable in the query. It's not really working for me, does anyone know how to do it properly?
Here is what i have so far.

```
$query = "SELECT column FROM `table` WHERE 'name' = '$_POST[checkname]'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ("no query");
$cod = mysqli_fetch($result);
echo $cod;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: [Escaping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) would help with doing it properly. Better yet [bound params](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli), which Mysqli already supports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mysqli supports prepared statements, which protect against sql injection attacks.  It would look like this:

```
/* Create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT column FROM table WHERE name=?");

/* Bind parameters */
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $_POST['checkname']);

/* Execute it */
$stmt -> execute();

/* Bind results */
$stmt -> bind_result($result);

/* Fetch the value */
$stmt -> fetch();

echo $result;
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for more info.

A quick rundown, in response to the comment:

- In `$stmt->prepare("...")`, you're forming your query, and you hold the place of any variables you intend to use with a "?"
- In `$stmt -> bind_param(...)`, you're binding the variables to their corresponding question mark.  The first argument is the type, the following arguments are the variables.  If you were using a string and an integer, inside the parenthesis it would look like `"si", $stringVar, $intVar`
- In `$stmt -> bind_result(...)` you are stating what you are binding the results to.  If the query was for a name and age, inside the parethesis would look like `$name, age`
- In `$stmt->fetch()`, you're fetching the result.  If it was multiple rows returned, you would do something like:

  while($stmt->fetch()) {
      //code here
  }

Alternatively, you could use PDO.  It would look something like this:

```
/* Create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column FROM table WHERE name=:checkname");

/* Bind parameters */
$stmt->bindParam(':checkname', $_POST['checkname']);

/* Execute it */
$stmt->execute();

/* Fetch results */
$obj = $stmt->fetchObject();

echo $obj->column;
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for more info.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm not quite up-to-date with whats happening in this, however i adapted it to mine and it works, so thanks for that! :)

Comment: No problem, any time!  I updated my answer to give a brief run down of what is going on in the code.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

//it is apsulutly

// work

if(isset($_POST['checkname']))
    {

```
    $post = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['  checkname  ']));

    $query = "SELECT column FROM `table` WHERE name = '$post'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ("no query");
    $cod = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
    echo implode($cod[0]);
    echo implode($cod[1]);//For particular cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it works, just try it out like this

following your code...

```
if(isset($_POST['checkname']))
    {
        //to avoid SQL injections
        $post = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['checkname']));

        $query = "SELECT column FROM `table` WHERE name = '$post'";``
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ("no query");
        $cod = mysqli_fetch($result);
        echo $cod;
    }
```

Comment: That line should be `$post = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['checkname']));`  As it is now it is missing the "i".  Prepared statements are the better route to take, though.